From text datetime to date in postgresql
I am to go from text column date which is stored like this:
1990-04-02T00:00:00.000
to a date in format 'YYYY-MM-DD'
how do i do this is postgresql?

select left('1990-04-02T00:00:00.000',10)::date;

or: select date('1990-04-02T00:00:00.000'::timestamp);

Just cast is to a date, since it's a valid timestamp:
SELECT CAST('1990-04-02T00:00:00.000' AS date);

You can alter the column in-place and specify your format as a to_date() mask:
alter table yourtable alter column yourcolumn type date using (to_date(yourcolumn,'YYYY-MM-DD')); Once you switch to date type, it doesn't have any actual format - it's just number, and the textual representation you see when you fetch the value is dictated by your DateStyle setting.
